How to initialize Isar using riverpod?
I use IsarDb as local db. I follow a method. But its sometime not initialize. please check my code. and provide a better solution or inform me where is issue. Some time it shows

Isar not initialized.
No message showed (just i cant pull data from isardb

1. Isar Service Page
class IsarService {
  late Isar isar;
  static final IsarService _instance = IsarService._internal();

  // Private constructor for the singleton
  IsarService._internal();

  factory IsarService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  final schemaList = [
    SearchedUserLocationSchema,
    SavedLocationModelSchema,
    SelectedUserLocationSchema
  ];

  Future<void> initIsar() async {
    try {
      isar = await Isar.open(
        maxSizeMiB: Isar.defaultMaxSizeMiB,
        directory: (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path,
        schemaList.cast<CollectionSchema>(),
        inspector: true,
      );

      kLog('Isar DB Initialized');
    } catch (e, s) {
      kLog(e);
      kLog(s);
    }
  }
}

2  Isar notifier / controller 

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'isar_service.dart';

final isarServiceController = FutureProvider<IsarService>((ref) async {
  final isarService = IsarService();
  await isarService.initIsar();
  return isarService;
});

3 Isar initialize (when app is run)
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) async {
      try {
     
        await ref.watch(isarServiceController.future);
      } catch (e, s) {
        kLog(e);
        kLog(s);
      }
    });


Why do you want to use riverpod in your specific case ?

I use riverpod for statemangement in my whole project
